# Server setup / Remote setup

Tags: git

I am not the one who setup our git system set up so I'm not sure if it was done incorrectly or if we are trying to pull incorrectly.

We have our server setup to have a `www2` folder where all of our files are. We have a git install in this folder and it seems to be working fine. A secondary folder was created outside of `www2`, but on the same level as the folder named `www2.git`. This folder contains what a normal `.git` folder would contain.

We have been pushing to `www2.git` (and all of the working files are on my local machine now). When we go to `www2` and run `git status` I get the expected result of not being able to see any pushes or status stating I'm behind or anything else. When I go to `www2.git` and run `git log` I get the expected result and see all the logs of commits that were submitted.

What I don't understand is how am I supposed to merge/pull/fetch/??? these commits into my current working directory. I have attempted to add a `git remote` and that works, but I can't figure out how to pull from it and creating a branch doesn't seem to work. The most common return I get is `xxx is outside of current repository`. (Obvious error.)

Am I going about this correctly or do I need to rebuild the project? If I'm going the right direction what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`www2` is a local clone of the bare repository `www2.git`. So someone essentially ran `git clone www2.git` before to create the `www2` folder.

Now, to update that local repository, you use it just like any other local repository. Inside of it, you can run `git fetch` or `git pull` to update the working directory which happens to contain the deployed server files.

Comment: So you were right for the most part. It looks like we had to connect more properly to the branches. We weren't branching 100% correct and needed to be changed. Thanks for the information!